# Problema al abrir proyectos de android studio en ubuntu

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu

Anteriormente utilizaba **Windows 10** pero me pase a **Ubuntu**, el problema es que al momento de abrir los proyectos de **android studio** que hice en **Windows 10** se tarda demasiado, no se si es normal porque lo esta descomprimiendo o me falta descargar o configurar algo.

GRACIAS!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si esta descargando las dependencias es importante verifiques las puede bajar sin problemas , si estas bajo un proxy puedes agregar las credenciales: Settings > Appearance & Behavior > HTTP Proxy @GustavoOliva

Comment: Pues con la información no creo que alguién te puede responder acertadamente, aunque es normal que la primera vez que se abra un proyecto este tarde, pues se debe ejecutar todas las tareas de descarga de dependencias, la construcción del proyecto para ese sistema operativo.
Creería conveniente especificar si esto te ocurre incluso despues de que ya has abierto el proyecto y el android studio ha realizado satisfactoriamente todas las tareas de indexación, compilado entre otras.